# How to truncate the .000 in .000Z in ISO 8601 data format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iso

I have the following for example:

```
var newDateTime = new Date(startDate + startTime + ' UTC');
var timeStart = newDateTime.toISOString();,
```

and console logged `timeStart` and got `2001-05-20T20:11:22.000Z` but would like to get rid of the .000, so like `2001-05-20T20:11:22Z`. How can I do so?

Comment: Have you tried to do a string replacement?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @Matthew Could you show an example so I can accept the answer and upvote? Didn't work on my end.

Comment: @Matthew Please let me know if you've seen my last comment